# Select from sql views in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I have a view in my database and I wanna get data from it.How can I get its data with DB class and also I have to apply a condition on it how can I do for it?
Here is my code:

```
$Buylist=DB::select('select oId,bName,bPrice from myshopping')->where('id','=',Auth::user()->id);
```

And how can I insert and delete and update it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide more info ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly suggest you to first [read the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) or [watch Jeffrey's Laravel 5 Fundamentals series](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals).

Assuming I understood your question, you want to apply `$BuyList` into the view controller. To do so, place and modify it in your desired controller method:

```
return view('buy-list', ['BuyList' => $BuyList]);
```

Creation to the DB should look like so:

```
App\Post::create([
    'message' => 'A new comment.',
]);
```